# why am i not getting any errror in this case

Tags: jquery

I am checking for two strings equality irrespective of their case and spaces.

I was using this code:

```
var reqstr = 'Test   ' ;
var requested_data_one = 'Test ' ;

var checkequality = reqstr.toUpperCase().tri === requested_data_one.toUpperCase().trim();

if(checkequality){   
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

As seen, I am purposefully giving `tri` instead of `trim()`, but why it is not throwing an error? This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dpL73v2y/

Please let me know if this is valid check or not.

Comment: Trying to access a property that does not exist returns undefined. You are comparing undefined against something that fails... So it is not really an error

Comment: Because `checkequality` is returns boolean value. There is no runtime error in this case. Whenever something in undefined then bool always returns false.

Comment: Try calling `.tri()` as if it was a method - now you will see the error you were expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Because JavaScript is interpreting `tri` as a property of the returned uppercase string object. No such property exists, but JavaScript will not error if you attempt to retrieve a non existent property - it will merely return undefined.

```
"foo".toUpperCase().bar; //undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code would result tri being taken as a property that doesn't exist

```
var checkequality = reqstr.toUpperCase().tri === requested_data_one.toUpperCase().trim();
```

However, if you change tri to a method call, you will get errors

```
var checkequality = reqstr.toUpperCase().tri() === requested_data_one.toUpperCase().trim();
// TypeError: reqstr.toUpperCase(...).tri is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Javascript` is assuming it to be a `property` and while in comaprision the undefined and trim  returns false